# How can I create an equals method to compare two objects in an array?

Tags: java

How I can compare each object in an array to identify if they are the same;
ex. compare a hockey player to a golfer and output they are not the same,
or compare two hockey players to each other and output that they are the same.

I am unsure how to implement this.

```
players[0] = new BaseballPlayer(...stuff);
players[1] = new FootBall(...stuff);
players[2] = new HockeyPlayer(...stuff);
players[3] = new Golfer(...stuff);
players[4] = new BaseballPlayer(...stuff);
players[5] = new FootBall(...stuff);
players[6] = new HockeyPlayer(...stuff);
players[7] = new Golfer(...stuff);
players[8] = new BaseballPlayer(...stuff);
players[9] = new FootBall(...stuff);
players[10] = new HockeyPlayer(...stuff);
players[11] = new Golfer(...stuff);
players[12] = new BaseballPlayer(...stuff);
players[13] = new FootBall(...stuff);
players[14] = new HockeyPlayer(...stuff);
players[15] = new Golfer(...stuff);
```

Comment: Implement a `Comparator` for the class you want to compare, and then use it in `Arrays.sort(...)`.

Comment: You need to implement `equals()` in each class (or in a shared superclass, which is easier).

Comment: @Kayaman and `hashCode()` for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Utilities to implement this have already been provided in the JDK. Please look at [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) documentation, specifically [deepEquals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object:A-) for verifying nested arrays.

Comment: `Arrays.equals()` (and `deepEquals()`) still requires the objects in the array to have `equals()` implemented correctly. Also, you misunderstand the question. It has nothing to do with arrays being equal.

Answer (score 0):

See [`Arrays.equals(Object[], Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[])) and implement `equals()` (and `hashCode()`) on your base class (I'm assuming all players inherit from the same `Player` class).

Comment: so lets say:  public static boolean equals(players[], players[]) {
  if (true) {
   System.out.println("related");
  } else
   System.out.println("not related");
 }

Comment: ^ does not compile not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @Jack, either hand-code the static method, or override `equals()` and `hashCode()` inside each class definition (or base-class, whichever makes more sense).

Comment: As for compile problems, well, just read what the compiler says ;) (try to name your parameters?)